# Find the extrema on a more general range of parameters

Tags: julia

Suppose I have the following `v` and `w` as follows:

```
julia> v = [1:3, 4:6, 1:2, 3:6, 1:6, 1:6];

julia> w = [1:3, 4:6, 1:6, 1:6, 1:6, 1:4, 5:6, 1:6];
```

and I want a function to return the minimum and the maximum which would cover all the values in the ranges, i.e. (1,6) in this case.

Currently, I've tried:

```
flatextrema(q) = 
  foldl((r,b)->
    (min(first(r),first(b)),max(last(r),last(b))), q; 
    init=(first(first(q)),last(first(q))))

flatextrema(q,r...) = 
  flatextrema((flatextrema(q),flatextrema.(r)...))
```

which gives me:

```
julia> flatextrema(v,w)
(1, 6)
```

Is there some nicer/shorter/faster way?

This version of `flatextrema` takes quite a wide range of possible parameters and returns a tuple.

Another example would be:

```
julia> flatextrema([1:3,2:4,3:5],[-3:3,1:4],10)
(-3, 10)
```

The idea is to get a minimum and a maximum which would include all scalars in the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You like any of these?

```
v = [1:3, 4:6, 1:2, 3:6, 1:6, 1:6]
w = [1:3, 4:6, 1:6, 1:6, 1:6, 1:4, 5:6, 1:6]

function flatextrema1(vs...)
   all_ranges = Iterators.flatten(vs)
   minimum(minimum.(all_ranges)), maximum(maximum.(all_ranges))
end

function flatextrema2(vs...)
   all_extrema = extrema.(Iterators.flatten(vs))
   minimum(first.(all_extrema)), maximum(last.(all_extrema))
end

function flatextrema3(vs...)
   all_extrema = extrema.(Iterators.flatten(vs))
   extrema(Iterators.flatten(all_extrema))
end

# flatextrema = flatextrema1
# flatextrema = flatextrema2
flatextrema = flatextrema3

flatextrema(v, w) # (1, 6)
flatextrema(v, w, 10) # (1, 10)
```

May be some cool way to do this with JuliaFolds/Transducers.jl - I need to check that package out properly.

---

Edit (after benchmark comment):

Ok here's a faster version

```
function flatextrema4(vs...)
   mn,mx = typemax(Int), typemin(Int)
   for cc in vs, c in cc
      cmn, cmx = extrema(c)
      mn, mx = min(mn, cmn), max(mx, cmx)
   end
   return mn, mx
end
```

---

Edit 2 (post accept): Bonus Transducer version (pretty fast and concise)

```
using Transducers
function flatextrema5(vs...)
   foldxl(ProductRF(min, max), vs |> Cat() |> Map(extrema))
end
```

I will note that while these solutions handle the amount of nesting in your examples, none of them are generic enough to handle arbitrary nesting. To do that you'd need a more generic, and likely slower, flattening step.

Comment: These options do the job, but they benchmark poorly relative to the option in the question (I used `@btime flatextrema(1:1000,1:200)` ). So there are multiple goals: performance, beauty and shortness. `Iterators.flatten` is more beautiful but takes a cost. Perhaps this is as good as it is right now.

Comment: New version looks both fast and nice :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try a function with `union`:

```
fe(ranges) = range(extrema(union(ranges...))...)

v = [1:3, 4:6, 1:2, 3:6, 1:6, 1:6];
w = [1:3, 4:6, 1:6, 1:6, 1:6, 1:4, 5:6, 1:6]
@show fe(v), fe(w) # (fe(v), fe(w)) = (1:6, 1:6)
```

Comment: This gets the a range covering `v` and `w`, but I meant to get a cover for both of them (or more vectors) at once. Also, `union` would be slow, as the `union` of ranges is a set and might even be complex set with holes.